# Creating a dynamic grid control

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, itemscontrol

While working in WPF i have the need for a Dynamic Grid. By this i mean a grid that contains only one kind of object, has a template for that object etc. But unlike a similar ItemsControl like a Listbox, i want the grid to be given a Maximum Columns property. This should act as a delimiter which will then calculate the number of rows needed based on the number of objects within the grid. To do this, i thought of inherriting a Grid to make use of its Row and Column properties, but i have a problem... I dont know how to implement an ItemsSource property outside of inherriting the ItemsSource from an ItemsControl...

so my question comes in two parts...

1. Am i pursuing this the right way? should i be inherriting ItemsControl and trying to re-implement the Grid behavior
2. if this is the right way to do it, how do i implement an ItemsSource property with its corresponding ItemTemplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a better way would be to use a `ListView`? Here is an example how to achieve 3-column output: http://kristofmattei.be/2010/03/16/multi-column-listview/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx)? If you set the Columns property (and don't set the Rows property), it will automatically figure out how many rows to create to hold its items.

Comment: Your answer and Vlad's are both similar in that they use different implementations of a UniformGrid. I will try them both out, but Thank you! i didnt know of this controls existence

Comment: UniformGrid doesn't seem to offer features like ItemsSource.

Comment: That is the reason i gave yours the tick :) UniformGrid is used in both, and supplies most of the features i want, but blending it with a Listbox provides all the functionality i need

Comment: Yes, I should have thought of that in my answer. You can't bind directly to a UniformGrid; you have to set it as the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl. See the examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx but use a UniformGrid instead of a StackPanel.